Reference request for non-banded Toeplitz matrix
I want to know references that treat the property of eigenvalues and eigenstates of the non-banded Toeplitz matrix.
I mean for example, the Toeplitz matrix $A$ whose matrix element is given by $A_{ij}=|i-j|^\alpha, (\alpha \in \mathbb{R})$.
I found “Spectral Properties of Banded Toeplitz Matrices” by A. Böttcher and S. Grudsky, but it may mainly contain the banded Toeplitz matrix.
Are there any famous and comprehensive papers or books?
